# Extracting similar observations from both datasets in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with several variables of diagnosis codes. I used proc transpose to combine those into a single variable “dxcode1” in a new dataset called “diags”. I also have a dictionary containing “ICD-10 codes”, description, AIS severity and ISS body region. The dictionary was in excel file (csv) and I imported it into SAS just like my dataset. I m interested in a new dataset that shows me those specific diagnosis codes which are in ICD-10 dictionary as well as in the variable (dxcode1) in my dataset. so, I actually want to match my dataset codes with the ones in the dictionary. I tried proc compare and proc sql but proc sql gives me an error that says “expecting a ‘.’, syntax error, statement will be ignored”

Here is my code:

```
Proc SQL;
create table matched as select y.*
From dictionary x, diags y
Where dictionary.code = diags.dxcode1;
Quit;
```

I also tried this:

```
Proc sql
Create table matched as 
Select *
From diags, dictionary
Where diags.dxcode1=dictionary.code;
Quit;
```

Please help me out, I will be much obliged!!!

Comment: Your first example should use the  X and Y aliases in the WHERE condition.  Also DICTIONARY is the name of a special library in PROC SQL used for accessing metadata about objects in your current SAS session.  It might help to use a different name for that dataset to avoid confusion.

Comment: You say similar. `=` will check for exact matches so what does 'similar' mean to you? Definitely make the changes @Tom suggests first though.

Comment: Hi Reeza. I want the exact codes to be detected. Sorry if similar caused problem. I meant exact codes as I have in the dictionary. Thank you Tom. Let me try this and will get back.

Comment: I tried changing the name and the code worked but it only gave me one diagnosis code that occurs in both datasets. However, I manually scanned  both datasets and we have plenty of codes which are exact matches but there are thousands of them and I cannot use if/then statements. Is there something wrong with my SAS code? Or if someone knows of a more efficient function please let me know. I will really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `dictionary` is a sort of reserved word, because of the [dictionary tables and views](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/070-30.pdf) in SAS PROC SQL.  See this, which gives the same error:

```
data dictionary;
  set sashelp.class;
  keep name;
  where sex='M';
run;
data class;
  set sashelp.class;
run;


proc sql;
  select y.*
  from dictionary x, class y
  where dictionary.name = class.name
  ;
quit;
```

It's legal to have a dataset with that name, but inside `proc sql` it will cause problems.

Ideally, don't use `dictionary`, but if you want to, just prefix it with the library name (probably `WORK`):

```
proc sql;
  select y.*
  from work.dictionary x, class y
  where dictionary.name = class.name
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Tom - the slightly odd formulation is on purpose, as I'm mimicking OP's formulation of the final statement.  Yes, you could use x. / y., and it's somewhat odd not to, but it's intentionally showing that this is not the source of the error.